# Twilio/Python - 12200 Schema validation warning

Tags: python, twilio

Right now I have a program that receives an SMS message, posts the body of the message, and then forwards the SMS to another number. However I'm receiving an error from Twilio about the "Scheme validation." The code functions exactly as it should, but I'd like to fix the error.

Initially I had the following code:

```
import RUAlertsTwilioWEBSERVER
import twilio.twiml
import time
import praw

from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from passwords import *
from twilio import twiml

def login():
    r = praw.Reddit(app_ua)
    r.set_oauth_app_info(app_id, app_secret, app_uri)
    r.refresh_access_information(app_refresh)
    return r

r=RUAlertsTwilioWEBSERVER.login()
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def AlertService():
    TheMessage=request.form.get("Body")
    if (TheMessage != None):
        print(TheMessage)
        client.messages.create(to=ePhone,from_=tPhone,body=str(TheMessage))
        r.submit(*submit to reddit code*)
    return str(TheMessage)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

The Twilio debugger gives me 

`Content is not allowed in prolog. 
Warning - 12200
Schema validation warning
The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.`

I tried to get the XML needed for the post by changing my code to the following (Only the relevant part)

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def AlertService():
    TheMessage=request.form.get("Body")
    if (TheMessage != None):
        print(TheMessage)
        resp = twiml.Response()
        XML = resp.say(TheMessage)
        client.messages.create(to=ePhone,from_=tPhone,body=XML)
        r.submit(*submit to reddit code*)
        return str(resp)
    return str(TheMessage)
```

This code didn't work so I changed `body=XML` to `body=str(XML)`. However now it just sends the XML as the body and I receive the error:

`cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Say'. One of '{Sms, Message, Redirect}' is expected.
Warning - 12200
Schema validation warning
The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

`<Say>` is not a valid TwiML verb to include in response to a request made to a Message Request URL.  Its only valid for Voice Requests.

If you want to send a message back to the person who sent the text message to Twilio use the `<Message>` verb.

```
resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
resp.message(message)
```

Also, it looks like you are sending the TwiML as the message of the new outbound SMS message.  I think you can replace that with just the Body param.

```
client.messages.create(to=ePhone,from_=tPhone,body=TheMessage)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on this. I want to forward the SMS body sent to Twilio to another, 3rd number (not the sender or Twilio number).

When I used "say" it was just to get the XML formatting. 

This code `client.messages.create(to=ePhone,from_=tPhone,body=TheMessage)` works, but I still get errors from the debugger.

Comment: @DevinRader could you please check my question? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367898/twilio-quick-start-project-is-not-working